# sublime text 3 certificate verification failed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl-certificate, certificate

I was following the [official instruction](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html) to install Sublime text 3 but get errors shown as below when I do `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Ign:10 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
Hit:12 https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:13 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Release
Ign:14 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages
Ign:15 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Translation-en_US
Ign:16 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Translation-en
Ign:14 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages
Ign:15 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Translation-en_US
Ign:16 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Translation-en
Ign:14 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages
Ign:15 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Translation-en_US
Ign:16 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Translation-en
Ign:14 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages
Ign:15 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Translation-en_US
Ign:16 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Translation-en
Ign:14 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages
Ign:15 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Translation-en_US
Ign:16 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Translation-en
Err:14 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
Ign:15 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Translation-en_US
Ign:16 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://download.sublimetext.com/apt/stable/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I googled for a while but couldn't find the right solution for me. Any help is appreciated!

---

1. My environment is Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64, KDE plasma
2. My `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list` file:

```
deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
```

3. My `apt-transport-https` and `ca-certificates` are:

```
apt-transport-https is already the newest version (1.2.32).
ca-certificates is already the newest version (20170717~16.04.2).
```

4. The output of `apt-key list`:

```
...
pub   4096R/8A8F901A 2017-05-08
uid                  Sublime HQ Pty Ltd <support@sublimetext.com>
sub   4096R/BD3DF454 2017-05-08
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper CA certificate should already be in your bundle, so it's likely someone has messed with it. Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` and ensure that `mozilla/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt` is selected. Unless you have some extremely good reason for not doing so, every certificate should be selected. If that certificate does not appear in the list, then reinstall the package: `sudo apt install --reinstall ca-certificates`

Comment: So it seems that `mozilla/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt` is selected and every certificate is selected as well. How do I know which certificate is for `Sublime`? haven't recognized any certificate there that looks like it... Also I tried `sudo apt install --reinstall ca-certificates`, doesn't work.

Comment: They used Let's Encrypt, so that would be the CA certificate. Any online SSL checking tool will tell you which certificate is needed. Though at this point I think something even worse is wrong with your system. It's time to look at what changes have been made to it since installation.